# Linear span proof

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field, $A \in \cal{M}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{F})$
>   and $W=\left\{B \in {\cal{M}}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{F})|AB=BA \right\}$.
>   Suppose there exists a column vector $v \in  \mathbb{F}^n$ such that
>   $\left\{v,Av,A^2v,..., A^{n-1}v\right\}$ is a basis for
>   $\mathbb{F}^n$. Prove that $\left\{I,A,A^2,...,A^{n-1}\right\}$ is a
>   basis for $W$.
>   $(\cal{M}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{F})$ is the vector space comprising all $n\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{F}.)$

I'm done with the linear independence part, but to prove $\left\{I,A,A^2,...,A^{n-1}\right\}$ is indeed a basis I would need to prove $B=c_0I+c_1A+...+c_{n-1}A^{n-1}$ for some scalar $c_i$. However, since $Bv \in \mathbb{F}^n$ and $\left\{v,Av,A^2v,..., A^{n-1}v\right\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{F}^n$, I only have $Bv=(c_0I+c_1A+...+c_{n-1}A^{n-1})v$. How do I proceed from here to "eliminate" $v$ from the above equation? Would be very much appreciated if someone could shed me some light on this, thanks!

Comment: Since $\{v,\dots, A^{n-1}v\}$ is a basis of $F^n$  there exist $c_0,\dots, c_{n-1}$ that $Bv=c_0Iv+\cdots+c_{n-1}A^{n-1}v$.  Does this help?

Comment: I think I have already thought of it, but here $v$ is not an arbitrary vector in $\mathbb{F}^n$?

Comment: No, $v$ is *very special* by proposition...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $P$ be the matrix $(v\mid Av\mid A^2v\mid\cdots\mid A^{n-1}v)$. Suppose $AB=BA$ and $Bv = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} c_k A^kv$. Show that $BP=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} c_k A^kP$. Then the result follows because $P$ is invertible.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
$$Bx = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \lambda_k A^k v$$
For any $x$ (since we have a basis). Now check $ABx$ and $BAx$ and compare coefficients.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hint, but how can you compute $BAx$ from the given $Bx$?

Comment: You will know $$BAx = ABx$$
so you can "escape" that and see that if $$ABx = BAx \quad \forall\ x$$ then $B \in \langle A^k : k=0,\ldots, n-1\rangle$